# Ordering Javascript Array Based On Arbitrary Ordering

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Let's say I have a list of books that need to be ordered arbitrarily based on three languages. The book's language(s) is represented by a string. In books containing multiple languages, it is a comma-separated string of languages in which English will always come before Spanish and French, and Spanish will always come before French.

```
[
{ language: 'English' },
{ language: 'French' },
{ language: 'English, French' },
{ language: 'Spanish, French' },
{ language: 'English, Spanish, French' }
{ language: 'Spanish' }
]
```

If I wanted to order this array so that books with English always come first, then books with Spanish, then books with French, is there a way to do that other than making an array containing the correct order such as this

```
const orderArray = ['English', 'English, Spanish', 'English, Spanish, French', 'English, French', 'Spanish, French', 'Spanish', 'French']
```

and then looping over it with something like this?

```
const orderBooks = (books) => {
    const orderedBooks = [];
        orderArray.forEach((language) => {
            const bookIndex = books.findIndex(book => book.language === language);
            if (bookIndex >= 0) {
                orderedBooks.push(books[bookIndex]);
            }
        
    });
    return orderedBooks;
};
```

Would there be a way to order them based on some sort of simple preference array like this?

```
['English', 'Spanish', 'French']
```

Comment: _"Would there be a way..."_ - Sure. Split the language and compare the result of `preferenceArray.indexOf(language)`

Answer (score 0):

You could sort based on the first language that is in one book but not the other.

```
  books.sort((a, b) => {
     const difference = orderArray.find(language =>  
       a.includes(language) !== b.includes(language)
     );
     return a.includes(difference) - b.includes(difference);
 });
```

A more complex (/ elegant) implementation would be:

```
 const sortBy = (comp, ...others) => (a, b) =>
   a.includes(comp) - b.includes(comp) || sortBy(...others)(a, b);

 books.sort(sortBy(...preferenceArray));
```